# Azure Document Intelligence layout not recognizing "sections"

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

When I analyze PDFs with Azure Document Intelligence, the result doesn't recognize the 'sections' in a PDF page/layout, so the ordering of the resulting content is incorrect.

See the example screenshot below. The correct flow of the PDF is to follow the blue lines, whereas Azure will follow the red lines.

Is there any way to correct this?

[image: Example of Azure DI results]